# Best statistical method to compare model data with data from real measurements

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, method-comparison

I am relatively new to statistics therefore my question may be a bit silly, but I would like to compare data (soil water content) obtained from a mathematical model with data obtained from real measurements (same site) and determine if the model data is statistically significantly different from the measurements.

An example of the data is provided below:

| Year | Day of year | Model data | Field data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 242 | 0.43 | 0.40 |
| 2 | 234 | 0.37 | 0.39 |
| 3 | 244 | 0.30 | 0.30 |
| 4 | 244 | 0.33 | 0.37 |
| 5 | 239 | 0.37 | 0.35 |
| 6 | 229 | 0.36 | 0.38 |
| 7 | 254 | 0.44 | 0.41 |

Which statistical method will be the best for the mentioned statistical analysis? I was thinking about the T-test, but since the values are not normally distributed, I am leaning towards the Mann-Whitney U Test. What is your opinion on this? Which analysis would you recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a few details about the context? You don't need a statistical test to conclude that your model fits and measurements come from different distributions. You might want to use such a test to compare the residuals from two different models. If you just want to quantify the discrepancy between actuals and fits, you could use established error measures from forecasting.

Comment: It may be a good idea to establish what level of discrepancy is significant for your application. This is what should drive your analysis. For example, for soil water content, what is the level of noise you pick up as a result of measurement? What is the natural variability? If I measure two patches of soil 10cm apart and get different readings, is that  difference small enough to be ignored?

Comment: [MW U Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)'s null hypothesis is that probability of X>Y is equal to probability of X<Y (for randomly selected) X and Y. So if I had two normal distributions with equal means but different variances I could get it to fit Mann-Whitney U test despite the different distributions. Does this suit you?

Comment: The size of the difference should be considered.  Is the difference in means large enough to be of interest (in the event that it is statistically significant).

Comment: Is the mean difference or the mean of the absolute difference that is most of interest to you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-parametric Wilcoxon signed rank test to determine if the distribution of the observed values is significantly different from the modeled.  If the data were more normally-distributed you could run the paired t-test.   Wilcoxon signed rank test is the non-parametric variant of the paired t-test.  FYI, Mann-Whitney is almost identical to the Wilcoxon rank sum test for 2 groups, and these are the non-parametric variants of the 2-group t-test.  However, you don't have groups, so you have to run paired tests.